# I want to include the uploaded file in my project when i submit my form (c#)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

The error message I got:

> {"L'accès au chemin d'accès 'F:\ABOUDASADOK
>   WORKSPACE\new\TaysirRdlc\TaysirRdlc\Reports\Rdlcs\Application
>   2\RDLC TEST1\V88\sadek.rdlc' est refusé."}

my Action is:
'

```
public ActionResult Create(Rdlc rdlc, HttpPostedFileBase UploadFile) 
{
        Application currentApplication = db.Applications.Find(rdlc.ApplicationID);

        string AppNamePath = currentApplication.ApplicationName;
        string ModulePath = rdlc.Name;
        string VersionPath = rdlc.Version;
        string rdlcsPath = "Rdlcs";
        string reportsPath = @"~\Reports";

        string generatedPath = Path.Combine(reportsPath, rdlcsPath, AppNamePath, ModulePath, VersionPath);
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(generatedPath), UploadFile.FileName);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path).GetAccessControl();
        UploadFile.SaveAs(path);
        rdlc.File = UploadFile.FileName;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Rdlcs.Add(rdlc);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new {message = "successfully uploaded" });
        }
        ViewBag.ApplicationID = new SelectList(db.Applications, "ApplicationID", "ApplicationName", rdlc.ApplicationID);
        return View(rdlc);
    }
```

'

Comment: copy paste that config file here please.

Comment: Please translate the error message and explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem
the error was in this Line

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(path).GetAccessControl();
```

I was passsing the name of the file inside the path, and that caused the problem
the solution is:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(generatedPath));
```

Comment: but i still can't make the created file included in my project :(